# Calling unmanaged 32bit DLL exception occuring only on one user's computer: BadImageFormatException (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

Tags: dll, unmanaged, 32-bit, hresult, badimageformatexception

Our application is C# .Net 4 and calls an unmanaged 32bit DLL. It's been working fine and runs many machines (mostly 64bit Windows 7). However, I recently encountered one particular user on whose machine the program traps with BadImageFormatException as soon as the call into the unmanaged DLL is made.

> BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an
>   incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

I've done the following:

1. Ensured the install and files are correct
2. Matched his .Net runtime updates as closely as possible to working machines
3. Ensured all projects' **platform target are set to x86**
4. Run a **debug build, which works**

I'm nearing my wit's end. Any suggestions? **Is there a particular .Net 4 update or hotfix the lack of which cause this type of issue?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turns out to be some misplaced/invalid system files on the user's machine, which can manifest as "The Application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application" when starting certain applications.

> The problem was due to 32/64-bit mismatches of various system dlls
>   required by Visual studio. Somehow the dlls it needs got replaced by
>   64-bit versions that it couldn’t load.
>
> Replacing the dlls mentioned below from a machine that is working
>   solves the problem:
>
> c:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp100.dll c:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp100d.dll
>   c:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100.dll
>   c:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100_clr0400.dll
>   c:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/96035692-9a50-40d4-a7d3-48bda87d11ec